# How to create mask from image directly?

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

I want to create a mask for my video processing using python. I have the optical flow mask as in first image(a) and I need to create the mask shown in second image (b). Is there any image processing algorithm to do so? All answers are welcome and thanks in advance.

[image: image a]  [image: image b]

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind is that first you can turn the left image into a binary image, then use dilation to make all of these lines be a single block. After that, you can calculate corner points of blob and draw lines from those points.

Comment: Thank you. I will try accordingly.. :-)

Comment: you can use convexHull function but you would first have to remove the outliers

Comment: Yeah.. that's right. I am trying with convexhull.